# Return certain record based on criteria

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Take this list of results

```
  Date     | YESorNO
---------------------
01/01/2001 | NO
01/01/2002 | NO
01/01/2003 | YES
01/01/2004 | NO
01/01/2005 | NO
01/01/2006 | NO
01/01/2007 | YES
01/01/2008 | YES
01/01/2009 | YES
```

The list is ordered and I cannot sort this is any other way other than descending / ascending.

I want to be able to return the first 'YES' after all 'NO's have been accounted for.

In the above example, row 7 is the record I want returned (on 01/01/2007)

My code is as follows

```
var query = 
(
    from m in db.MyTable
    where m.Criteria == XYZ
    select new
    {
      Date = m.Date, 
      YESorNO = m.YESorNO
    }
).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

Using `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.YesOrNO == "YES")` returns the 3rd record.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it have to be Linq?  You can do it easily in one pass with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Sorry yes, no iteration as the actual query will be over thousands of records

Comment: Sort for yesorno then get the first yes, what's the problem?

Comment: Then I think you need tow passes - one to find the highest "NO" date and one to find the earliest "YES" value after that date.  Or use a direct SQL query.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria this is precisely what I don't want to do. How will that give me the record from 2007?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by ordering descending and take the last element of the first group of "YES":

```
var query = 
(
    from m in db.MyTable
    where m.Criteria == XYZ
    select new
    {
      Date = m.Date, 
      YESorNO = m.YESorNO
    }
).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);

var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .TakeWhile(x => x.YESorNO == "YES")
                  .LastOrDefault();
```

I use `AsEnumerable()` here, because I'm not sure which operators are translatable into SQL, `TakeWhile` is surely not.

---

If there is no "YES" after the latest "NO", this returns `null`.

Comment: @RyanSearle I'm sure it compiles, but I'm also sure you get an exception when executing it. At least I can't imagine how the resulting SQL should looklike , but I missed some of last decade's improvements in SQL...

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm surprised too about TakeWhile. But afaik LastOrDefault still don't work with EF

Comment: @RenéVogt thanks, this has certainly helped. I however missed a vital part in my question. Follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114138/return-certain-record-based-on-criteria-2

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = db.MyTable
    .Where(m.Criteria == XYZ)
    .Select(e => new { Date = e.Date, YESorNO = e.YESorNO })
    .OrderBy(e => x.Date);

var latestNODate = query.Where(ee => ee.YESorNO == "NO").Last().Date;
var element = query.Where(e => e.Date > latestNODate && e.YESorNO == "YES").FirstOrDefault();
```