# Return certain record based on criteria (2)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I asked this question previously, but missed a vital part of my problem.

[Return certain record based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099125/return-certain-record-based-on-criteria)

Take this list of results

```
Client  |   Date     | YESorNO
-------------------------------
A1      | 01/01/2001 | NO
A1      | 01/01/2002 | NO
A1      | 01/01/2003 | YES
A1      | 01/01/2004 | NO
A1      | 01/01/2005 | NO
A1      | 01/01/2006 | NO
A1      | 01/01/2007 | YES
A1      | 01/01/2008 | YES
A1      | 01/01/2009 | YES

A2      | 01/01/2001 | NO
A2      | 01/01/2002 | NO
A2      | 01/01/2003 | YES
A2      | 01/01/2004 | NO
A2      | 01/01/2005 | YES
A2      | 01/01/2006 | YES

A3      | 01/01/2001 | NO

           ...etc...
```

The list is ordered chronologically and I cannot sort this is any other way other than descending / ascending.

I cannot sort for Yes | NO and find the First() or Last() as this won't give me the required value.

**I want to be able to return the first 'YES' after all 'NO's have been accounted for, per Client.**

In the above example for Client[A1] row 7 is the record I want returned (on 01/01/2007).

Client[A2] - row 5 (01/01/2005) ..etc

My code is as follows

```
var query = 
(
    from m in db.MyTable
    where m.Criteria == XYZ
    select new
    {
      Client = m.Client,
      Date = m.Date, 
      YESorNO = m.YESorNO
    }
).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

Using `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.YesOrNO == "YES")` returns the 3rd record.

User @RenéVogt advised that

```
var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .TakeWhile(x => x.YESorNO == "YES")
                  .LastOrDefault();
```

would get the job done and it does, but I forgot to add that the query will be returning many Clients and I need the first 'YES' for each Client, therefore the above code won't suffice.

Iterating over my results would be hugely time consuming and whilst that is a solution I would prefer this logic to be within the database query itself (if possible)

Many thanks

Comment: You could do it easily in 2 queries.  Grab a list of all the "NO"s for each client... only selecting the last no for each client.  Then use that to ask for a list of the first "YES" after the last "NO" by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is grouping by `client`,and then find the last `YES` of each one **starting from the end**. Something like this (`ClientList` is a `List<>`, you may have to change it depending on where is your data):

```
var query = ClientList.OrderBy(x => x.client).ThenBy(x => x.date).GroupBy(x => x.client);
foreach (var client in query)
{
    var lastYES=client.Reverse().TakeWhile(x => x.YESorNO == "YES")
              .LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",client.Key,lastYES.date));
}
//Output: A1 01/01/2007 0:00:00
//        A2 01/01/2005 0:00:00
```

**Edit**

Mansur Anorboev rightly suggested ordering by descending date, thus eliminating the need of `Reverse`, so the code would be:

```
var query = ClientList.OrderBy(x => x.client).ThenByDescending(x => x.date).GroupBy(x => x.client);
foreach (var client in query)
{
    var lastYES=client.TakeWhile(x => x.YESorNO == "YES")
              .LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",client.Key,lastYES.date));
}
```

**Edit 2**

I still was not completly happy with my solution, as it is using a foreach. This does everything in one Linq command:

```
var query = ClientList.OrderBy(x => x.client)
                      .ThenByDescending(x => x.date)
                      .GroupBy(x => x.client, (key, g) => g.TakeWhile(x => x.YESorNO == "YES").LastOrDefault())
                      .ToList();
```

This returns a list with one element per client and with the correct date.

Comment: nice solution. I think would be better to use ThenByDescending(x => x.date) and remove Revers()

Comment: You are completly right @MansurAnorboev. Answer edited

Comment: Now that I see OP linked first question, it seems this is not very original, as  @RenéVogt accepted answer does this. But the `GroupBy` client part maybe what OP neeeded, so i'll leave this answer

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a little sql query

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Client DESC) AS rn  
    FROM [dbo].[tblSkaterhaz]
)
,gte AS (
    SELECT Client,max(rn) mx FROM cte 
    WHERE YesOrNo = 'NO'  
    GROUP BY Client 
)
SELECT cte.* FROM gte
INNER JOIN cte on cte.Client = gte.Client and cte.rn = gte.mx + 1
```

Although it is not the required solution, but it yields the required result. You can create a stored proc and use it in your code.

NOTE: This is tested against the same table (and data) mentioned in question above

I hope this will be helpful for you.